Issues getting my R Markdown file to open/save in PDF form
I am following along in my Coursera Module with an activity for exporting some R Markdown files to have saved in both HTML and PDF. The PDF version does not want to open up.
Any suggestions? I'm very new to R so I know this may seem rather basic or silly. I really appreciate
the support!
---
title: "R Markdown Intro"
author: "Miles"
date: "2024-04-09"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

{r, include=FALSE}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)


## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring:

* HTML
* PDF 
* MS Word documents.

For more details on using R Markdown click here [link](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com).

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

{r cars}
summary(cars)

